# Kendo UI Grid: show DetailTemplate with conditions

Tags: c#, user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to show DetailTemplate for Kendo UI Grid by conditions.

I tried the following cases:

```
detailTemplate: '#if(ResultDate!= null){ =kendo.template($("#detailRequestTemplate").html()) }#',
```

and

```
detailTemplate: function (e) {
    if (ResultDate != null)
    { 
        return kendo.template($("#detailRequestTemplate").html());
    }
},
```

both of them don't work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it:

```
                            dataBound: function (e) {
                                var items = e.sender.items();
                                items.each(function () {
                                    var row = $(this);
                                    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
                                    if (ResultDate !== null) {
                                        row.find(".k-hierarchy-cell").html("");
                                    }

                                })
                            },
```

This code removes an "arrow", if condition is false

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this logic inside the template instead.

```html
<div id="grid"></div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="detailRequestTemplate">
    #if(ResultDate !== null) {#
        //...your template html
    #}#
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#detailRequestTemplate").html()),
        });
    });
</script>
```

For a more complete example, look at this [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IdeSuHAs).

Also take a look at Telerik's [Templates Overview](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) documentation.

Comment: no-no, in this case I have an arrow. I want to avoid it